# Execution order with javascript and race conditions?

Tags: javascript

I was under the impression that javascript executed all lines at the same time and this is one thing that makes it different from many other programming languages. I have the following code for a simple index;

```
var newAcceptIndex = 0;
function addNewAccept(event) {
    var newAccept = `some new accept ${newAcceptIndex}`
    $(event.target).closest("[id^='new_item_']").before(newAccept);
    newAcceptIndex += 1
};
```

I would have expected newAcceptIndex on the first call to be 1 since all code should be executed at the same time and thus set to 1 instead of 0. Am I encountering a race condition or is this working as intended?

Comment: You are printing the newAcceptIndex before you increment it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The fastest way to get great help is to ask a question with high quality. Your code has several flaws that prevent it from working that would show up in any debugger. Please consider correcting your syntax mistakes and providing a complete, verifiable working bit of code for us to help you with. thanks. This: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

JS code does not run all at the same time, you're probably just thinking about the [hoisting JS does with their variables and functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) so they don't immediately throw errors. You just need to reorganize your code like how it would be in other programming languages - executed from top to bottom:

```
var newAcceptIndex = 0;
function addNewAccept(event) {
    newAcceptIndex += 1
    var newAccept = `some new accept ${newAcceptIndex}`
    $(event.target).closest("[id^='new_item_']").before(newAccept);
};
```